# Select2 - how to display returned json data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Here is what the json string looks like that gets returned from my page:

```
{"osoby":["jeden","dwa","trzy","cztery","piec"]}
```

Firebug claims everything is working perfectly but none of the data shows up in the select2 plugin.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Should it be returning column names or something?

select2 call:

```
$("#complogi").select2({
    multiple: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "cdop",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',

        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term,
                action: 'getEventsComplogs'
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try `return {results: data.osoby};`

Comment: @Saqueib, `{results: data.osoby};` returns error in firebog
`typeError: a is undefinied   select2.min.js`

Comment: `console.log(data)` and see whats the structure of returned json

Comment: @Saqueib `{"osoby":["jeden","dwa","trzy","cztery","piec"]}`

Comment: can you share a screenshot of response in firebug or google chrome dev tool, use this to upload image http://imgur.com/

Comment: @Saqueib `http://i.imgur.com/hrLia3U.png`

Comment: addig this two lines
        `formatResult: function (item) { return item; },`
        `formatSelection: function (item) { return item; }`
fix problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return data is not well formatted to be used in select2, you will required data in below format

```
{id: 1, text: 'jeden'}
```

If you can modify it from back end will be great

of format the result

```
formatResult: function (item) { return item; },
formatSelection: function (item) { return item; }
```